# How to change css on click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue with the links in my dropdown nav menu. I believe that the issue is due to an owl carousel that is in the body, because when I inspect the nav items (right-click inspect element) the console highlights the owl-carousel, also when I change the .owl-carousel display to none in the console, then the links in the nav menu will work (color change on hover, mouse changes to pointer). Therefore, I want to change the .owl-carousel display to none when the toggle menu is active (when the burger menu is clicked).

```js
var burgerMenu = function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".js-fh5co-nav-toggle", function() {
    $("#fh5co-nav > ul > li").css({ marginLeft: -50, opacity: 0 });
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    var mainNav = $("#fh5co-main-nav");
    mainNav.slideToggle(400).toggleClass("active");

    if (mainNav.hasClass("active")) {
      menuAnimate(1, 0, 400, 200);
    } else {
      menuAnimate(0, -50, 1, 0);
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<!-- Mobile Toggle Menu Button -->
<a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle"><i></i></a>
<!-- End Mobile Toggle Menu Button -->
<!-- Main Nav -->
<div id="fh5co-main-nav">
  <nav id="fh5co-nav" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/products.html">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="/location.html">Location</a></li>
      <li><a href="/cafe.html">Cafe</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<!-- End Main Nav -->
```

I don't really have any idea how to go about this. I have tried adding:

`$('.owl-carousel').css({display: none});`

to the burgerMenu function, but this changed nothing.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

***EDIT:
thanks! .css({"display": "none"}) - this worked, but something i didn't think of - the other pages don't have an owl-carousel and I am still having this problem. I think the best thing would be to just have the body shift down when the nav menu is clicked - is this possible? any ideas? thanks, again.

Comment: You need quotes on your values e.g. `.css({"display": "none"})` https://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Brackets within the .css are optional. You can simply write it as .css("display", "none");

Comment: @RohanRao if you don't use brackets, you need a `,` not `:`. You can also only set one property with that method.

Comment: @bhmahler oh yes! my bad. Just got out of my mind. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: thanks! .css({"display": "none"})  - this worked, but something i didn't think of - the other pages don't have an owl-carousel and I am still having this problem. I think the best thing would be to just have the body shift down when the nav menu is clicked - is this possible? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.owl-carousel').css("display", "none");
```

try this instead of

```
$('.owl-carousel').css({display: none})
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively since you don't have dynamic css, you can use another class and the class:

in your css file:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

and in you js:

```
$('.owl-carousel').addClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the below code.

```js
$('#hello').click(function() {
    $('#hello').css({
        'background-color': 'blue',
        'color': 'white',
      'font-size' : '35px'
    });
});
```

```css
#hello{
  cursor : pointer
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hello">hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using core JS:

`document.getElementById("my_custom_id").style.color="red";`

In the above line of code you can set any CSS, I set the `color` to `red` for `my_custom_id`.